# Why this javascript code snippet will print 414243?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

The environment is Nodejs.And I have a base function named `readFile` to read one file asynchronously:

```js
let fs = require('fs')
function readFile(fileName) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    fs.readFile(fileName,function (error,data) {
      if(error) return reject(error)
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Also I have a function named `readAll` to read all the files:

```js
async function readAll(paths){
  const promises = paths.map(async path => {
    return Promise.resolve(readFile(path)).then(res => {
      const r = res
      return r.toString()
    })    
  })
  for(var promise of promises){
    console.log(4)
    console.log(await promise)   
  }
}
```

And I call the `readAll` function like this:

(the content of 1.txt is `1`，2.txt is `2` and 3.txt is `3` ):

```js
readAll(['1.txt','2.txt','3.txt'])
```

I think it will print like this:

```js
4
Promise<pending>
4
Promise<pending>
4
Promise<pending>
```

But no,it just print each content of the files normally,which is `4 1 4 2 4 3`.And I can't understand why.
I analysis the print result according the event loop:

1.In the first loop,the whole script is a macro task and we run it.

2.When call `paths.map` method,we iterate the array.Each iteration will run the `async` function thus put the callback of `then` method into the Promise queue(micro taskqueue).

3.Then move on,we reach the `for...of` loop(until now we still execute the macro task).Since this loop is synchronous,the two `console.log` will be called.

4.Here,I thought each loop will print `4` and `Promise<pending>`.Because we still haven't run the callback(in the queue) of `then` yet,which means it's impossible to get the content of each file.But the result is opposite because it actually print the content of each file!

But why? Is there something wrong with me? I can't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is here

```
console.log(await promise)
```

inside your readAll.

When you do an await, it makes the javascript wait for the promise to return. That's why you got the finished promise results. If you change the above to simply

```
console.log(promise)
```

You will see

```
4
Promise<pending>
4
Promise<pending>
4
Promise<pending>
```

in your program output since here the javascript doesn't wait for the promise to return.

Answer (score 0):

`await` for the promise to resolve and push the data to the `promises` for each loop

```
async function readAll(paths){
    for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
      var data = await Promise.resolve(readFile(path)).then(res => {
       const r = res
       return r.toString()
      })   
      promises.push(data);
    }
    for(var promise of promises){
     console.log(4)
     console.log(await promise)   
    }
 }
```